# How can you perform the same tests as Effort using only Moq?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework-6, moq, effort

Presently, I have setup a lot of tests including data access layer and business logic layer tests using Effort (see https://effort.codeplex.com/).  We have already been using Moq in our unit tests, and my boss would like to keep things simple, so he wants me to see if I can move the tests over from the Effort implementation to us only Moq and FakeDbSet (see http://aikmeng.com/post/62817541825/how-to-mock-dbcontext-and-dbset-with-moq-for-unit), to make the code base simpler to maintain.

From what I understand, Effort basically mimics an entire SQL Server database in memory.  So it seems like it would take a lot of code using Moq to set everything up so that a test can be run using only that.  Does anyone have any thoughts on this?  Can it even be done without a huge amount of coding?  Does anyone have any suggestions?  TIA.

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to test, and how your tests are currently written. If they're true unit tests, and they typically just get data from a pretend database and then do something with it, you can create mocks that will return the data you're pretending exists in the database. If you're testing a whole scenario, where you're testing multiple classes and methods that create and retrieve data from various tables, it's going to be a lot more difficult to mock reliably.

Comment: Also bear in mind that there are a lot of LINQ expressions that will work in C#, but not when translated to SQL. You won't be able to test that the data access layer is working with a high degree of certainty if you're not allowing it to produce SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up staying with Effort.  Using FakeDbSet and Moq required a lot more setup and caused some LINQ queries to fail in the unit tests even though they work in a production situation.

**UPDATE:**

It turns out that it was not a problem with FakeDbSet or Moq--there were problems in my LINQ query where it would fail if there were null string values.